# How to insert quotes in list to separate items?

Tags: python, list

NEW QUESTION:

So I have the list a:

```
a = ["abcd"]
```

but I want it to be:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

The list I'm working with is very long (200 terms long; not 4)

So how do I make Python put a quote (") after each letter so they're individual terms? Because I don't want to manually do this for all my lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [4]: a = ["abcd"]

In [5]: list(a[0])
Out[5]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

For previous version:

```
In [3]: a = ["a,b,c,d"]

In [4]: a[0].split(",")
Out[4]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: >>> a = ["a,b,c,d"]
>>> a[0].split(",")
>>> print a
<<< ['a,b,c,d']

This is what I get

Comment: This answer doesn't change `a`, it is creating a new list and simply writing it to the console.

Comment: What about `a = ["abcd"]`?

Comment: @JacobWheeler If `a = ["abcd"]` you can do `list(a[0])`, and please don't modify the question, when you do this in invalidates all answers which causes confusion and inconvenience. Just ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

@Akavall's answer is very good, but in case you are dealing with a list with possible whitespace around the commas like this:

```
my_list = ["a, b, c, d"]
```

You'll want to strip the resulting items like so:

```
new_list = [x.strip() for x in my_list.split(',')]
```

For a list like this:

```
my_list = ["abcd"]
```

you'll need a different approach.  Just do:

```
new_list = list(a[0])
```

Comment: What about `a = ["abcd"]`?

Comment: Then you're just screwed man, nothing is going to work in every single possible situation.